# BadPaddingException when calling STS after token expiring

Tags: cxf, ws-security

I am getting a BadPaddingException when trying to request a new token from an STS using a CXF (v 3.0.6) client configured in Spring XML.

I can get a token on the first attempt and use it to call the target webservice several times successfuly, but when the token expires I can't get a new one. I get a BadPaddingException, when decrypting the STS response.

I have set the "AllowRenewing" property of the STSClient to false since the STS I am calling does not allow renewing.

Here is my Spring config of the CXF client

```
    <util:properties id="signatureProperties">
        <!-- keystore -->
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider">org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin</prop>
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">jks</prop>
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">${SMDB_KEYSTORE_PATH}</prop>
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias">${SMDB_KEYSTORE_ALIAS}</prop>
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">${SMDB_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}</prop>
        <!-- truststore -->
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.type">jks</prop>
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.alias">${SMDB_TRUSTSTORE_SERVICE_ALIAS}</prop>
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.file">${SMDB_TRUSTSTORE_PATH}</prop>
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.password">${SMDB_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <util:properties id="stsEncryptionProperties">
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">jks</prop>
        <!--prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.provider">SunPKCS11</prop-->
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">${SMDB_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}</prop>
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">${SMDB_TRUSTSTORE_PATH}</prop>
        <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias">${SMDB_TRUSTSTORE_STS_ALIAS}</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <jaxws:client name="{http://smdb.dst.dk/api/external/v1/}SoapBinding_ISecureIndsaetData"
                  createdFromAPI="true"
                  wsdlLocation="wsdl/smdb-secureindsaetdata.wsdl"
                  address="${SMDB_INSERT_DATA_WEBSERVICE_URL}">
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="ws-security.sts.applies-to" value="${SMDB_STS_APPLIES_TO}" />
            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="${SMDB_TRUSTSTORE_SERVICE_ALIAS}" />
            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value-ref="signatureProperties" />
            <entry key="ws-security.signature.username" value="${SMDB_KEYSTORE_ALIAS}" />
            <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value-ref="signatureProperties" />
            <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value-ref="clientCallbackHandler" />

            <!-- the response from the STS is not BSP 1.1 compliant (missing c14n transform in the signature) -->
            <entry key="ws-security.is-bsp-compliant" value="false" />
            <entry key="ws-security.sts.client">
                <bean class="com.systematic.cura.integration.smdb.security.DigstSTSClient">
                    <constructor-arg ref="cxf" />

                    <property name="wsdlLocation" value="wsdl/sts.wsdl" />
                    <property name="serviceName" value="{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/}SecurityTokenService" />
                    <property name="endpointName" value="{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/}STS_Port" />
                    <property name="endpointAddress" value="https://${SMDB_STS_SERVICE_HOST}:${SMDB_STS_SERVICE_PORT}/SecurityTokenService.svc" />
                    <property name="allowRenewing" value="false"/>
                    <property name="enableLifetime" value="true"/>
                    <property name="ttl" value="60"/>

                    <property name="properties">
                        <map>
                            <entry key="ws-security.signature.username" value="${SMDB_KEYSTORE_ALIAS}" />
                            <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value-ref="signatureProperties" />
                            <entry key="ws-security.asymmetric.signature.algorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="${SMDB_TRUSTSTORE_STS_ALIAS}" />
                            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value-ref="stsEncryptionProperties" />
                        </map>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </jaxws:properties>
    </jaxws:client>
```

The error i get is this:

```
2019-10-08 09:36:20.500 INFO  class=o.a.c.s.S.S.STS thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 3
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Content-Length=[16558], content-type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8], Date=[Tue, 08 Oct 2019 07:36:20 GMT], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/10.0], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], X-served-by=[001]}
Payload: <S11:Envelope xmlns:S11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><S11:Header><wsa:Action wsu:Id="action">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue</wsa:Action><wsa:MessageID wsu:Id="messageid">uuid:0311ce73-d06c-4b7c-9aeb-df3c58880b1d</wsa:MessageID><wsa:RelatesTo wsu:Id="relatesto">uuid:9abfda57-0eb4-474b-8de1-eeb217ab173c</wsa:RelatesTo><wsse:Security S11:mustUnderstand="1"><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="sec_timestamp"><wsu:Created>2019-10-08T07:36:20.452Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2019-10-08T07:37:20.086Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#action"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>EsbIUxpFxODWjQNQay887WVHi0rRyqunTS6rvEEwU8k=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#messageid"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>MBQpLzrEtwy7YVe+pWYGhOa5x3NyqibYX/grvREIjRU=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#relatesto"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>fhLVST5j8jwSDU0cA7le7YqkkpXQo71uTBD0/crLqUQ=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#sec_timestamp"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>U0Fs+DT+n5mWHq9pNYQ5dtCye/LTdI+fAZHopJvdpz0=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#body"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>+h4qIDCdWOy8++pYKI3iKRtc1rhcIx1GJNzEWS6YYac=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>Ps+39jnZeJES04GElgbWqlfR1LohFUDjobuhH+QHZutYz7TSSTwaiStGsN4bnMo0qF079V6TyrU5qfp709jxzi3pzAC/5EMnWbGdv755G55h9w1opFTABbJGz3z2XGXrzgdisp/GxDmRyiZ93GMxhDHY/sx8M3f5HaYhj9dAUlrjUAhZHxq7m5zzdcvm5Bd8u18YXd6iiugqGN0hKf1WybaxAcHODMe//I9zJUF8SadRVU54Q9NBpYup7ow3NLfdZ8QgxzuOTwwHpchhOQUyn7D33xAtxSF3iw0Ah59anE/QYuLRiG8C4Cam7L9U5zUEkaaa8Vv+aSz8X4G//YZMRg==</SignatureValue></Signature></wsse:Security></S11:Header><S11:Body wsu:Id="body"><RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512"><RequestSecurityTokenResponse Context="urn:uuid:2790a13e-76e4-4bf3-b48f-dab9d5f166b7"><TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0</TokenType><AppliesTo xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy"><EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><Address>https://sts.saml.test.smdb.dst.dk/</Address></EndpointReference></AppliesTo><RequestedSecurityToken><EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" wsu:Id="encryptedassertion" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/></e:EncryptionMethod><KeyInfo><o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><X509Data><X509IssuerSerial><X509IssuerName>CN=TRUST2408 Systemtest XIX CA, O=TRUST2408, C=DK</X509IssuerName><X509SerialNumber>1478018816</X509SerialNumber></X509IssuerSerial></X509Data></o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo><e:CipherData><e:CipherValue>U2aYJQ5NdZObrbSbdQe1xjyE9VszM3XnXTFe4oPK4fLf7HXqz2//yeBSeOXKjqW2pFII1Xo5uFfQFT2zNjPZ7Zfk+blo6x33OOAfmKGhy304NZ9TxQJa6skoQQZC8pgHtGNo/yoA3n8sbT+iYi2vFtnRqLOhp1r5TwwoDoeKui+C9IcxcwSw86+aYYHvHEoi33rikrOXRX0TC5/COo7vFY/EIGnWI1/7dOoG8ird5av9AlnKBVjNvyEsjPS8pjHAbKwBx4liLGW4lDY1GOCnUajogamLgABMM3dpg3lU8Gm5HX3p9Gu8UPVRsBUD4nUSKAq9qEX1USUYa2cQdefB0w==</e:CipherValue></e:CipherData></e:EncryptedKey></KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>FCMNCuFPUQ0P/aPDjBUw6mTml+C5jrY8F696IFpAVM91z7koHwkCK+SH9...</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></EncryptedAssertion></RequestedSecurityToken><wst:RequestedAttachedReference xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference><wsse:Reference URI="#encryptedassertion"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></wst:RequestedAttachedReference><wst:RequestedUnattachedReference xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference><wsse:Reference URI="#encryptedassertion"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></wst:RequestedUnattachedReference><Lifetime><Created xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2019-10-08T07:36:20.452Z</Created><Expires xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2019-10-08T07:37:20.086Z</Expires></Lifetime></RequestSecurityTokenResponse></RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection></S11:Body></S11:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
2019-10-08 09:36:20.506 FINE  class=o.a.c.w.s.w.WSS4JInInterceptor thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" WSS4JInInterceptor: enter handleMessage()
2019-10-08 09:36:20.510 DEBUG class=o.a.j.x.d.i.d.DOMSignatureMethod thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" Signature provider:SunRsaSign version 1.8
2019-10-08 09:36:20.511 DEBUG class=o.a.j.x.d.i.d.DOMSignatureMethod thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" Verifying with key: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 1777916757386031245861122923257003193285780018460556568365356826910491627286858802420774031270781...
  public exponent: 65537
2019-10-08 09:36:20.511 DEBUG class=o.a.j.x.d.i.d.DOMSignatureMethod thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" JCA Algorithm: SHA256withRSA
2019-10-08 09:36:20.511 DEBUG class=o.a.j.x.d.i.d.DOMSignatureMethod thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" Signature Bytes length: 256
2019-10-08 09:36:20.511 DEBUG class=o.a.j.x.d.i.d.ApacheCanonicalizer thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" Created transform for algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
2019-10-08 09:36:20.511 DEBUG class=o.a.j.x.d.i.d.ApacheCanonicalizer thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" isNodeSet() = true
2019-10-08 09:36:20.512 DEBUG class=o.a.j.x.d.i.d.DOMSignedInfo thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" Canonicalized SignedInfo:
2019-10-08 09:36:20.512 DEBUG class=o.a.j.x.d.i.d.DOMSignedInfo thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" <SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#action"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>EsbIUxpFxODWjQNQay887WVHi0rRyqunTS6rvEEwU8k=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#messageid"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>MBQpLzrEtwy7YVe+pWYGhOa5x3NyqibYX/grvREIjRU=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#relatesto"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>fhLVST5j8jwSDU0cA7le7YqkkpXQo71uTBD0/crLqUQ=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#sec_timestamp"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>U0Fs+DT+n5mWHq9pNYQ5dtCye/LTdI+fAZHopJvdpz0=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#body"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>+h4qIDCdWOy8++pYKI3iKRtc1rhcIx1GJNzEWS6YYac=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo>
2019-10-08 09:36:20.512 DEBUG class=o.a.j.x.d.i.d.DOMSignedInfo thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" Data to be signed/verified:PFNpZ25lZEluZm8geG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvMDkveG1sZHNpZyMiPjxDYW5vbmljYWxpemF0aW9uTWV0a...
2019-10-08 09:36:20.517 WARNING class=o.a.c.p.PhaseInterceptorChain thread="smdb-scheduler_Worker-4" Interceptor for {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/}SecurityTokenService#{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/}Issue has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.createSoapFault(WSS4JUtils.java:268)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:333)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:190)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:802)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1644)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1532)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:652)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.AbstractSTSClient.issue(AbstractSTSClient.java:848)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.IssuedTokenInterceptorProvider$IssuedTokenOutInterceptor.getTokenFromSTS(IssuedTokenInterceptorProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.IssuedTokenInterceptorProvider$IssuedTokenOutInterceptor.issueToken(IssuedTokenInterceptorProvider.java:528)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.IssuedTokenInterceptorProvider$IssuedTokenOutInterceptor.renewToken(IssuedTokenInterceptorProvider.java:429)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.IssuedTokenInterceptorProvider$IssuedTokenOutInterceptor.handleMessage(IssuedTokenInterceptorProvider.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:138)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.indsaetAnmodning(Unknown Source)
    at com.systematic.cura.integration.smdb.webserviceclient.SmdbInsertDataClient.submit(SmdbInsertDataClient.java:69)
    at com.systematic.cura.integration.smdb.webserviceclient.SmdbInsertDataClient$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cc38b014.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.systematic.cura.integration.smdb.webserviceclient.SmdbInsertDataClient$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbe21249.submit(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:472)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:291)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:264)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:178)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at com.systematic.cura.integration.common.logging.FlowIdInterceptor.lambda$wrapProcessorInInterceptors$0(FlowIdInterceptor.java:33)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:84)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at com.systematic.cura.integration.common.logging.FlowIdInterceptor.lambda$wrapProcessorInInterceptors$0(FlowIdInterceptor.java:33)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at com.systematic.cura.integration.common.logging.FlowIdInterceptor.lambda$wrapProcessorInInterceptors$0(FlowIdInterceptor.java:33)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:695)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:623)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:247)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:114)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at com.systematic.cura.integration.common.logging.FlowIdInterceptor.lambda$wrapProcessorInInterceptors$0(FlowIdInterceptor.java:33)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.QueueLoadBalancer.process(QueueLoadBalancer.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerSupport.process(LoadBalancerSupport.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:58)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:450)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:224)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:428)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:278)
    ... 107 more
```

However debugging shows that the origins of the error is a BadPaddingException from the RSAPadding class in the rt.jar file of my jdk (jdk1.8.0_221).

```
 javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:383)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:294)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:194)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1222)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:655)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignatureMethod.verify(DOMSignatureMethod.java:238)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature$DOMSignatureValue.validate(DOMXMLSignature.java:562)
    at org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.validate(DOMXMLSignature.java:254)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:224)
```

I have tried adding ssl debugging and ws-security debug logging, but I can't see any difference between the first and the second call to the STS.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Seems that the public key used to decrypt the message the second time has changed to be the public key found in the keystore from the signature properties instead of the key from the trust store, that is pointed out in the encryption properties.

Comment: Ended up resetting parts of the context in our subclass of the STS client (DigstSTSClient) to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

During startup of your application, log the content of this array:

```
Security.getProviders()
```

It's possible that you have several implementations on the classpath (e.g. Java 8 and Bouncy Castle). They don't support the same algorithms and sometimes, decoding something that was encoded with the other causes `BadPaddingException`.

This can also mean that the STS is using Bouncy Caste and your Java 8 can't parse the output.